# How to know the real file type of files inside a zip or tar.gz file?

Tags: linux, zip, gzip

I have multiple .tar.gz and .zip files and I wanted to know the file types of files inside these files without extracting them. How can I achieve this. I can list the files of .tar.gz using the command `tar -tzf 'filename'` and `unzip -l 'filename'` . I could not find a way to identify the file types inside these files. How can I achive this? I am using centos 6.6

Output of command `tar -tzf 'test.tar.gz'`

```
-rw-r--r-- root/root     89403 2019-05-26 11:31 abc.tar.gz
-rw------- root/root      2842 2019-05-26 09:41 anaconda-ks.cfg
-rw-r--r-- root/root      8823 2019-05-26 09:41 install.log
-rw-r--r-- root/root      3314 2019-05-26 09:40 install.log.syslog
-rw-r--r-- root/root    122880 2019-05-26 11:28 tin.tar
-rw-r--r-- root/root     25543 2019-05-26 11:20 tito.zip
-rw-r--r-- root/root     25487 2019-05-27 07:48 tito.ZIP
```

output of `unzip -l test.zip`

```
 Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
    89403  05-26-2019 11:31   abc.tar.gz
     2842  05-26-2019 09:41   anaconda-ks.cfg
     8823  05-26-2019 09:41   install.log
     3314  05-26-2019 09:40   install.log.syslog
   122880  05-26-2019 11:28   tin.tar
    25543  05-26-2019 11:20   tito.zip
    25487  05-27-2019 07:48   tito.ZIP
---------                     -------
   278292                     7 files
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `tar`:

```
tar --to-command='exec file -b -' -xvvf file.tar.gz
```

For `zip` files, you could convert to `tar` on the fly using `bsdtar` and use GNU `tar` again to call `file` on each member:

```
bsdtar cf - @file.zip | tar --to-command='exec file -b -' -xvvf -
```

It gives an output like:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 0/0            7653 1999-12-30 10:26 WINOBJ.HLP
MS Windows 3.1 help, Thu Dec 30 15:26:17 1999, 7653 bytes
-rw-rw-r-- 0/0            7005 2006-07-28 08:32 Eula.txt
Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
-rw-rw-r-- 0/0          729464 2011-02-14 11:37 Winobj.exe
PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
```

The `file` command guesses the *type* of a file using heuristics based on the first few bytes of the file. So, in any case the data needs to be extracted from the file. Even to report the `tar tvf` output, `tar` needs to read and uncompress the full archive as the information is stored before the content of each archive member, but none of those solutions above extract the members **to disk**, the data is passed from `bsdtar` to `tar` and from `tar` to `file` via pipes, the content of the archive members is not even stored as a whole in memory.

After `file` returns after having read the first few bytes of the file, GNU `tar` handles it smartly and skips the rest of the archive  member (instead of dying of a SIGPIPE) before running the next `file` command for the next archive member.

Where it's not optimal from an efficiency point of view is that it runs one `sh` (to interpret the `exec file -b -` command line) and one `file` command for each regular file archive member. We use `exec` so that the same process is reused for `sh` and `file` (for those `sh` implementations like `dash` that don't do that optimisation by themselves).

Answer (score 0):

The `file` command should tell you about the file itself:

```bsh
$ file test.zip
test.zip: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
$ file test.tar.gz
test.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, last modified: Sun May 26 11:28:34 2019, from Uniz
```

But for the files inside the archives, you'd need to extract them and run `file` on each one individually.